# Push notification not receive with content_available

Tags: ios, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working with **firebase** to add push notification feature to an app, everything is fine with the push notification it self but in some state of the app the push notification is not receive.

Foreground / Background:

```
{
    "data":{
        "title": "title",
        "message": "message"
    },
    "content_available":true,
    "priority":"high",
    "registration_ids":[
        ""
    ]
}
```

The problem comes when the app is **killed by the user**, I send the same http request but the app didn't receive the remote notification.

I was testing with the console on firebase and when the app is killed the notification it's receive but I couldn't replicate the **console request** to **http request**

this is the content of notification when I made it through **firebase console**

```
[
    "google.c.a.c_l": label optional, 
    "google.c.a.e": 1, 
    "google.c.a.ts": IntValue, 
    "google.c.a.udt": 0, 
    "gcm.n.e": 1, 
    "aps": {
        alert = {
           body = mensaje;
           title = title;
        };
    }, 
    "google.c.a.c_id": IntValue, 
    "gcm.message_id": 0:1502103735577088%9218dc2f9218dc2f
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how iOS works, basically. When your app is killed by the user, it no longer receives background notifications.

Here's a somewhat-old-but-still-accurate link with some more detailed information: http://samwize.com/2015/08/07/how-to-handle-remote-notification-with-background-mode-enabled/